# is there a problem in the answer? finiding an angle

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

Can you tell me if there's an error in the answer ?

Given isosceles $\triangle ABC$ ($AB=AC$) and $AB=b$.

$BD$ is perpendicular to $AC$ and $DE$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

$\angle BAC=2x$.

The question is what should be $\angle BAC$ so $DE$ will be maximum ?

The answer is $109.47^\circ$ but isn't it an angle in a right triangle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you already know how to solve the problem and have got the following relation:

$$ DE = b\sin2x\sin x$$

Since $x$ can only take values in $(0, \pi/4]$ in order to not violate any triangle properties, we need to maximize DE in this interval to get the correct answer. You'll find that $DE$ increases monotonically in the said interval. So, at $x = \pi/4$, $A$ and $D$ are the same point (your problem doesn't prohibit that) and $DE_{max} = b/\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $D\in AC$ and $E\in BC$.
Note that $BD=b\sin2x$ and $DE=BD\sin\angle BCD$. Since $\angle BCD=\frac \pi2-\angle ACB = \frac\pi2-\frac{\pi-2x}2=x$, we find
$$ DE = b\sin2x\sin x$$
which you can maximize with calculus methods.
This task may be simplified if you let $y=\cos x$ and observe that
$$ \sin 2x\sin x=2\sin^2x\cos x=2(1-\cos^2x)\cos x=2(y-y^3).$$

Comment: i know how "to solve" it, my problem is that triangle $ABD$ as a right angle so how can angle $BAC$ be $109.47^0$?

Comment: because then the sum of angles in triangle $BAD$ is more than $180^0$

Comment: @daveo How is the sum of angles in $BAD$ more than $180^\circ$? Make a sketch. You will find that $\angle BAC=109.47^\circ$ and $\angle DAB=70.53^\circ$.

Comment: but $\angle BDA=90^\circ$